# SQL Group by Count of Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my script

```
SELECT COUNT( [Id]) as [Count Of Register],
Tag as [Tag]
FROM [Members]
Group By Tag 
Order By [Count Of Register] Desc;
```

Returned table is like this:

```
Count   Tag

550 ----1
550 ----2
545 ----3
545 ----4
545 ----5
```

So, this time I need Count of Tag, Group by this new Count field.

Some Returned Values Like:

```
2 ---550
3 ---545
```

Is there any way without using new table or Template Table or any Storage Table just by query?

Comment: What are your desired results? `(550,2),(545,3)`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I edit question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT [Count Of Register], COUNT(1) [Grouped Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT( [Id]) as [Count Of Register],
           Tag as [Tag]
    FROM [Members]
    Group By Tag 

) MyTable
GROUP BY [Count Of Register]
```

Comment: There is an error: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: D'oh, yeah, sorry about that, you can't use order by in an inner query! Sample fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
SELECT [Count Of Register], COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT([Id]) as [Count Of Register], Tag as [Tag]
     FROM [Members] GROUP BY Tag) q
GROUP BY [Count Of Register]
```

Comment: There is an error: Invalid column name 'Tag'.  for Count(Tag)

Answer (score -1):

mysql> create table order1(counter int(3) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> tag int(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into order1 values(500,20);//insert somany values as u required and check
       insert into order1 values(500,20);
       insert into order1 values(600,20);
mysql> select counter,count(*) from order1 group by counter